# How can we create extension methods for non-global interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I'm currently learning TypeScript but am thoroughly stumped at how to implement extension methods for non-global interfaces. Consider the following example: say I have an `interface` defining a `Cart` like so:

```
interface Cart {
    id(): string,
    name(): string,
    quantity(): number

    /* Other methods */
}
```

Then, I'd like to add an extension method similar to the following:

```
Cart.prototype.isValid = function() {
    return this.quantity() > 0;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work since `Cart` is not a type but I'm confused because `Promise` is also defined as an `interface`, yet I can successfully add extension methods to it. For example:

```
declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        hello(): string
    }
}

Promise.prototype.hello = function() {
    return "Hello!";
}

export {};
```

Is it possible to extend non-global interfaces like `Cart` and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: don`t think it is possible or useful somehow. Interface should not be changed during runtime. Otherwise it would make impossible type checking during compilation.

Comment: what you can do is to create another type that would be a combination of few interfaces: `type Blah = Foo & Bar`

Comment: You are looking for module augmentation and interfaces merging https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Cart is just a type. There's no object, you can't extend a prototype of a type/interface ref. There's no prototype to extend, you could do it with some object that implements Cart.

In the case of Promise, it's a browser API, if you got to you console on the Browser and type Promise you will see you have a object there. When you extend promise prototype like the example you gave you are not extending the interface but this object provided.

One possible solution if you want to do so is interface composition like:

```
interface CartSpecial extends Cart {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So `Promise` is definitely an object, but the problem is that the TypeScript definition for it is as an `interface`. My question is, how/why does that work but not my `Cart` example? What do I need to do to achieve the same behavior for `Cart`, as I can with `Promise`?

Comment: You can't like that. TypeScript knows that your Promise is some provided API. You are not extending the interface, you are a global variable declared on promise.d.ts file ( that's overwritten by the browser api ). When you extend Promise you are extending ```declare var Promise: PromiseConstructor;``` that has the prototype declared there: ```interface PromiseConstructor {
    /**
     * A reference to the prototype.
     */
    readonly prototype: Promise<any>;```